# Clicking on a confirmation alert using Capybara and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

In one of my views I have this link:

`link_to 'Destroy', team, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }`

In my rspec feature spec I want to simulate clicking on the "OK" button. I thought I could do this:

```
page.accept_alert 'Are you sure?' do
  click_button('OK')
end
```

but that results in:

```
Failure/Error: page.accept_alert 'Are you sure?' do
 Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:
   Capybara::Driver::Base#accept_modal
```

What is the correct way to do this with rspec and capybara?

Answer (score 4):

As the error states, the driver you are using in Capybara doesn't support the modal API. If you're using rack-test it's because it doesn't support JavaScript at all so modals don't happen anyway. If you're using poltergeist it's because they haven't released a version with support for the Capybara modal API yet - see https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/pull/516

Answer (score 2):

I think it's [confirm](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session:accept_confirm) window not [alert](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Session:accept_alert)

```
page.accept_confirm do
  click_button('OK')
end
```

Comment: The failure is still the same: `Capybara::NotSupportedByDriverError:`

Comment: @RobertJoseph Are you sure you correctly set the driver to capybara-webkit? The default driver (rack test) throws that error.

Comment: @Arsen how to set the drier to capybara-webkit? I'm facing the same issue